# Seeking downloadable images for night?

Tags: data, satellite

Where can I download freely available images for night from for South Asian region?

[image]?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are [DMSP-OLS Nighttime Lights Time Series](https://ngdc.noaa.gov/eog/dmsp/downloadV4composites.html) data that can be download from NOAA website. The files are:

> Cloud-free composites made using all the available archived DMSP-OLS
>   smooth resolution data for calendar years. In cases where two
>   satellites were collecting data - two composites were produced. The
>   products are 30 arc second grids, spanning -180 to 180 degrees
>   longitude and -65 to 75 degrees latitude.

Which means it covers South Asian region.

Comment: Is it available till 2013 only! Isn't possible to get it from 2017 ?

Comment: @Mehmud the best and direct way to know is to send them an email asking whether 2017 data are available or not. But I think you need to accept this answer if it helped you to know the source of data you were asking.

Comment: Ok thank you. I will accept your answer definitely, if get no other replies regarding it for data after 2013.

Answer (score 0):

There is [another question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/160279/free-open-satellite-or-other-remote-sensing-data-for-night-time) addressing this topic, maybe it can give you som extra information.