# Is it possible to detect human settlements by night light data?

Tags: remote-sensing, night-time-images

I am working on a project in which human settlements are identified using geo-tagged Twitter data. Since this project is focused on developing countries (mostly African), I am afraid that many human settlements may not be identified because Twitter may not be used there much.

I have been thinking about using night light satellite imagery instead. My assumption is that if there is Twitter data, there is electricity and therefore there is likely to be streetlights or other light pollution. I would like to try this method and compare the results.

**Question:** Are there high-resolution night light datasets available that have the potential to produce accurate information about human settlements? Are there perhaps some drawbacks or problems with this approach that would preclude this method from success?

Comment: It is possible but if the settlements are not big or bright enough you won't be able to detect them since the resolution of these open datasets might be to coarse.
You can find some links in this question: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/160279/free-open-satellite-or-other-remote-sensing-data-for-night-time

Comment: Another helpful link to a paper commenting on this difficulty in detecting low density or small developing settlements: https://sci-hub.tw/10.1016/j.rse.2017.11.026

Comment: The assumption about electricity usage is not true. Many places would have solar panels or other small energy generators that charge a battery, which in turn is used to charge cell phones or to provide a very limited amount of light. These places are unlikely to be detected at night.

Comment: @JGH Yes that is a good point. But there are likely also places with streetlights but no Twitter data. I cannot estimate if there is more of such settlements or more of those that you describe. Which is why I would like to try and see.